# UITableViewCell insert/add style green plus (+) button - how can I grab this image?

Tags: iphone, image, uibutton, addition, retina-display

I need to grab the image for the UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert button (green +). Of course, I would like to get it in the regular size and in 2x. I didn't think this would be so difficult, but I am having a hard time finding it. Is there a way to get this without a major hack?

Comment: If you test your app in the iPhone simulator and take screenshots with `Grab`, that should give you the images.

Comment: But will they be on a clear background? The buttons are round and shaded, and will go over gradients of various colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some sites that provide free downloadable vectors of the iPhone User Interface elements.  You should be able to get the green button from these packages.  Since they are vectors, you can resize them to any size you'd like without losing detail.

Here's one site that links to multiple sites offering these downloads:
[iPhone UI Elements](http://webdesignledger.com/freebies/11-ui-kits-for-iphone-and-ipad-development)

If none of these work for you, try searching online for something like 'iPhone vector UI elements.'

Comment: Thanks superjessi. I had actually found that page.. the one download that is supposed to be vector actually does not give you what it says it will, just some cut off images. The rest seem to be Photoshop, which I can't afford...

Comment: Don't purchase it. You can download trial version which has 30 days of validity.

Comment: Nitish, the option is not there to purchase it. I cannot get to the images at all. Still have not found a good solution, besides messing with some less than great quality pngs grabbed off of Google.

Comment: If you insist on opening photoshop files: try GIMP, or GIMPshop.  They are open source free alternatives.