# uitableview cell image - looking for the plus sign

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am looking to add the native "+" sign to one of my tableview cells but not sure if there is an attribute for that. I am basically looking to do whats in the image below but in a non editing mode (i know how to do that when in editing mode). Do i need to add this image manually or is it provided as part of the tableview cell API?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What should the sign do?

Comment: nothing. just an image - like any other image that you add to cell.imageView.image

Answer (score 6):

**Updated answer:**

Firstly, if you intend to have something that looks like an "insert item" control, but which doesn't actually add something to the table, you might be contravening the Human Interface Guidelines and Apple might reject your app from the store. Apple take a strong dislike to use of their standard HIG icons in ways that aren't standard, because doing that confuses users. Check out what they have to say in the section "*Standard Buttons for Use in Table Rows and Other UI Elements*" of the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW35). To quote:

> [Standard buttons] should be used according to their defined meaning,
>   as with all standard buttons and icons. In other words, avoid choosing
>   a button based on its appearance, without regard for its documented
>   meaning. For a discussion of the reasons why it’s important to use
>   these buttons correctly, see “[Use UI Elements Consistently](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW2).”

(This aside, if you're willing to throw caution to the wind and you'd like to find copies of UI iPhone graphics, please see the links given here: [UITableViewCell insert/add style green plus (+) button - how can I grab this image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655982/uitableviewcell-insert-add-style-green-plus-button-how-can-i-grab-this-ima)

Also, the blue (not green!) plus button as seen in Contacts is available as a custom UIButton: see `[UIButton buttonWithType:buttonType]` Valid button types listed [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIButtonType).)

If your green plus button control *should* add something to the table -- and the issue is just that you want the 'insert' control there all the time:

Try having the table constantly in 'edit' mode, but don't show an edit control on the Nav bar or similar. You can enable edit mode for a `UITableView` programmatically by setting the `editing` property. Do this early on in the lifecycle -- try setting it in `viewWillAppear`, perhaps.

**My original answer, about how to add 'Insert' icon (which wasn't the actual question, but the info may still be useful to some readers):**

Please read the Apple docs about `UITableView` [insertion and deletion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1).

To quote the relevant parts:

> A table view has an editing mode as well as its normal (selection)
>   mode. When a table view goes into editing mode, it displays the
>   editing and reordering controls associated with its rows. The editing
>   controls, which are in the left side of the row, allow the user to
>   insert and delete rows in the table view.
>
> When a table view enters editing mode and when users click an editing
>   control, the table view sends a series of messages to its data source
>   and delegate, but only if they implement these methods. These methods
>   allow the data source and delegate to refine the appearance and
>   behavior of rows in the table view; the messages also enable them to
>   carry out the deletion or insertion operation.

In particular, you're interested in this method:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

which is part of the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol, [docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

**Update**

Ok, to answer your original question:

**You need to add the image manually.**

Comment: please read my question again, that doesnt answer my question. thanks.

Comment: I have edited my answer, would you consider therefore removing the downvote please?

Comment: Ok, I've added a tiny bit to my answer the actual question you asked. Would you please accept my answer if you found it all all useful?

Comment: Actually, the UIButtonTypeContactAdd button is used within Apple's own music app to add a song to a playlist, so theoretically one should be able to use the + sign in a table view without repercussion. But who knows unless you try.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
UIButton *bn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
bn.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 25.0, 25.0);
bn.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[cell addSubview:bn];
```